# Date Time Format Conversion

Tags: python, list, datetime

I have a list of these;

```
datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 31, 19, 30)
```

I wish to create a list of these;

```
2011-01-31 17:30:00
```

How is this done in a loop?

Comment: Have you considered `datetime.strftime`, or even just `str`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[For `datetime` and `date` instances `str` returns ISO dates](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.__str__):

```
In [15]: dates = [datetime(2011, 1, 31, 19, 30)]

In [16]: [str(d) for d in dates]
Out[16]: 
['2011-01-31 19:30:00']
```

You can also call [`isoformat`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) method directly:

```
In [17]: [d.isoformat(sep=' ') for d in dates]
Out[17]: 
['2011-01-31 19:30:00']
```

Comment: sorry but i've tried that and the list still remains the same ; datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 14, 20, 30), datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 14, 21, 0), datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 14, 21, 30), datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 14, 22, 0)..... after the line [str(d) for d in dates]. how can this be??

Comment: @Mark, `[str(d) for d in dates]` creates a new list. You can do `dates = [str(d) for d in dates]`