# How to convert a tuple to string in python

Tags: python

the original list of tuple is:

```
[ (datetime.date(2014, 8, 3), datetime.date(2014, 8, 16)), (datetime.date(2014, 7, 20), datetime.date(2014, 8, 2))]
```

how to transform to `[('2014-08-03','2014-08-16'),('2014-07-20','2014-08-02')]` in one line.

Comment: What have you been trying so far?

Comment: `[date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for date in datelist]` or variants thereof.

Comment: What should the result look like?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25043190/date-time-format-conversion?lq=1), I'd say your question is a duplicate

Comment: There is never a good reason for doing anything "in one line".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [(datetime.date(2014, 8, 3), datetime.date(2014, 8, 16)), (datetime.date(2014, 7, 20), datetime.date(2014, 8, 2))]

[tuple(map(str, i)) for i in a]
```

Comment: great thx. That's what exactly I want

Answer (score 1):

A more readable way (perhaps because there is no nested list comprehension) is:

```
import datetime

date_list = [(datetime.date(2014, 8, 3), datetime.date(2014, 8, 16)),
             (datetime.date(2014, 7, 20), datetime.date(2014, 8, 2))]
date_list_strings = [(str(start), str(end)) for start, end in date_list]
>>> date_list_strings
[('2014-08-03', '2014-08-16'), ('2014-07-20', '2014-08-02')]
```

Comment: Good job detecting the "x" in this "xy problem" instance. :) +1